Subdecimals in ERC20 tokens and wallets?
Is there any standard or any discussion of standard for wallets to display not the standard unit of a token, but perhaps 10^-3n, such as one thousandth, one millionth. Much like wei, gigawei, etc. Both Ether and Bitcoin have very few "standard units", and one idea has been that people would deal in one thousandth of an ether or bitcoin, etc. I have a coin myself (built a people-vote consensus engine and proof-of-unique-human over the past 10 years, link) and I'm considering if I should imitate ether and bitcoin and have relatively few "standard units" (a few billion maybe) and instead rely on that people would display them in 1/1000th, 1/1000000th, etc. But I've never actually seen wallets have such a feature built-in, and that is why I ask here.
